# Does a 'reset password' website facility give away too much information?

Tags: web-application, passwords, design-flaw

If a website has a reset password facility *(which will e-mail the account holder a reset link)*, **does this facility reveal too much information by allowing someone to probe who holds an account by entering various e-mail addresses?**

On a login screen you can get around it revealing who holds an account by giving a generic "E-mail or password is incorrect" message when incorrect details are entered. Which could mean an account doesn't exist or that the password is wrong.

The only way I can think of not revealing who holds an account through a password reset link is to provide a generic message saying "You have been sent a reset link to your e-mail address, if you had an account, otherwise you'll need to create a new account" or words to that effect, whether or not a reset link could be successfully sent.

Comment: Well.. if you have some sort of an account number, you can ask the user to enter that to retrieve the password.

Comment: "too much information" is subjective.   How much is too much?  You seem to be really asking "Is there a way to prevent an adversary from using the reset password facility to enumerate accounts.  In which case as @Tobias states, you've answered your own question.

Comment: For a very thorough treatment of your question (and other stuff associated with it,) see [Troy Hunt's](http://www.troyhunt.com/2012/05/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know.html) writeup. It will indeed tell you everything you want to know.

Comment: @hsnm But then you have to have a process for "I forgot/don't have my account number" and you'll likely end up with the same problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, if you don't permit duplicate email addresses, your _signup_ screen could be used to do verify them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You already answered the question youself: The only way to not give away any information is to display a generic "A message has been sent to a@b.c" after requesting a passwort reset, even if there is no account associated with that email. See also [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/12823/is-it-secure-to-have-an-email-no-longer-available-feature-on-your-registration/12892#12892) for additional details.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, could be, but application owner could limit the number of attempts from particular IP-addresses. Another layer could be that entered e-mail address validity could be checked in the application database. Another possibility is to ask e-mail address two times and disable clipboard in the second field, so it always should be typed manually.

Otherwise you are absolutely right.

Answer (score 0):

Are you protecting the bank accounts of people involved in illicit transactions?  If so, then permitting an adversary to elicit email addresses/credentials is probably unwise.

Are you protecting my display preferences on a public website?  If so, then the "reset password" facility is boring.

As someone else has said, all security controls have a cost; the art is to balance cost, risk, and consequence.